# Python locking from event listener

Tags: python, locking

So I have a websocket that listens to messages and when it receives the desired message it calls a run() function. Because it takes a while for run() to run to completion and there could be multiple messages during this time, I want to lock this function so that at any one time it is only running once. If a message is received during this time, I just want to ignore it. However I am not getting the lock mechanism to work correctly.

```
def __init__(self):
   self.lock = threading.Lock()

def process_message(self, msg):
   some_obj.run(self.lock)
```

Some other class:

```
def run(self,lock):
    acquired = lock.acquire(False)
    try:
        if acquired:

            print("not locked")
        else:
            print("locked")
    finally:
        if acquired:
            lock.release()
            print("released")
```

I expect to get a series of locked/not locked/released but I am only getting locked and released. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a very rudimentary implementation aim to reproduce you problem:

```
from threading import Lock
lock=Lock()
contador = 0
while contador < 5:
    if contador == 4:
        a = lock.acquire(False)
    acquired = lock.acquire(False)
    try:
        if acquired:

            print("not locked", contador)


        else:
            print("locked")
    finally:
        contador += 1
        if acquired:
            lock.release()
            print("released")
```

with following result:

```
$ python tester02.py 
not locked 0
released
not locked 1
released
not locked 2
released
not locked 3
released
locked
```

Run function seems correct. As far as I can see in you piece of code, I believe that **lock** should not be an instance attribute.